# Cauchy sequence less than a convergent series in a metric space $(X, d)$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $B_n$ be a sequence such that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n$$ converges.

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in some metric space $(X, d)$ such that $d(x_n, x_{n+1})$ $\le$ $B_n$ for each $n$, then the sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. 
If the sequence converges to $a \in X$ then is...? 
$$d(x_n, a) \le \sum_{k=n}^\infty B_k \textrm{ for every } n \in \Bbb N$$

This seems intuitive if we pick $n$ large since the tails of the series converges to  zero, but what about the first few terms in the sequence? These could be large values and these large values need not be less than the sum of the series  for small $n$. We would only need  $d(x_n, a)$ to be less than the series at *some* value of $n$, at which point all the subsequent values will be less than the series for all $n \ge N$ (some $N \in \Bbb N$) and hence the sequence converges.

Supposedly the answer is for all $n \in \Bbb N$. What am I not seeing here?

Comment: $d(x_n,a) = \lim_N d(x_n,x_N) \le \lim_N \sum_{k=n}^{N-1} d(x_n,x_{n+1}) \le \lim_N \sum_{k=n}^{N-1} B_k = \sum_{k=n}^\infty B_k$.

Comment: How do you know the first inequality? That the distance from a point in the sequence to its limit is less than or equal to the summation of all the values $d(x_n, x_{n+1})$?

Comment: huh? the first inequality says nothing about the limit $a$.... the first inequality is merely the triangle inequality..

Comment: I think mathworker21 meant to put $k$ in the summation, so the inequality reads $$\lim_N d(x_n,x_N) \leq \lim_N\sum_{k=n}^{N-1}d(x_k,x_{k+1})$$ which is an expanded version of the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\ \epsilon>0.\ $ Then there exists natural $\ M\ >\ n\ $ such that $\ d(x_{_M}\ a) < \epsilon.\ $ Then

$$ d(x_n\ a)\ <\ d(x_n\ x_M) + \epsilon\ \le
\ \sum_{k=n}^{M-1}\,B_k\ +\ \epsilon
\ \le\ \sum_{k=n}^\infty\ B_k\ +\ \epsilon $$
hence
$$ \forall_{\epsilon > 0}\quad d(x_n\ a)\ <
     \ \sum_{k=n}^\infty\ B_k\ +\ \epsilon $$
hence
$$ d(x_n\ a)\ \le\ \sum_{k=n}^\infty\ B_k $$
*Done.*